# PHP string concatenation - text disappearing

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I'm getting some apparently strange behaviour* while trying to concatenate strings in PHP.

I've pared down the following code to show where the problem lies:

```
class htmlElement
{
    private $tagName;
    public function __construct($tagName)
    {
        $this->setTagName($tagName);
    }
    public function setTagName($tagName)
    {
        $this->tagName = is_string($tagName) ? $tagName : NULL;
    }
    public function getTagName()
    {
        return (string)$this->tagName;
    }
    public function getHtml()
    {
        $tagName = $this->getTagName();
        $html = "<" . $tagName . "></" . $tagName . ">";
        return $html;
    }
}
$div = new htmlElement("div");
var_dump($div->getHtml());
```

The result of the var dump is:

```
string(11) "
"
```

The length (11) seems to be correct, but where is the text?!

*I assume it's not actually strange behaviour, and that I'm missing something really obvious!

Comment: You're looking at this *in your browser*? Then the browser is trying to interpret any `<..>` string as HTML tag. Look at the raw source...

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://repl.it/C8k3

Comment: Check it like this: `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($div->getHtml()));`Your browser is 'hiding' it.

Comment: see the source of site ctrl + u : )

Comment: @ʰᵈˑthanks for the replicate link - I'd used PhpFiddle which gave the results which I thought was strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior is not strange, text does have `<div></div>` inside it. But as you print it in web/mobile browser it renders as **HTML** instead of plain text.

Demo: https://eval.in/600675

Comment: Aha!  This obviously isn't where my problem lies then.  I'll keep looking!

Comment: It happen sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

due to the browser tag is not showing .you can check using cmd .your code is fine.[image]